# Apache POI open JavaDoc gives error: configure URL

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-poi, javadoc

I have downloaded latest Apache
POI from here: http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/poi/release/bin/poi-bin-3.10-FINAL-20140208.zip

There is a directory docs. I set it as java doc path in project setup, but it does not work.

I set javadoc as: `D:/Programowanie/poi-3.10-FINAL/docs/apidocs/`

The message I get when I want to open javadoc is:
[image]